# Calling the OneToOneField on Template in Django for the UserProfile Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I can't get the info from the `UserProfile` fields to display on the template (HTML) for each user who has logged in.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
  profile_views = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = '25')
```

Template codes that I have tried:

```
{{ user.userprofile.profile_views }}
{{ request.user.userprofile.profile_views }}
```

and any other combination I got online.

My **admin.py** looks like this:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):    
  model = UserProfile
  can_delete = False
  verbose_name_plural = 'User Account'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):    
  inlines = (UserProfileInline,)        
  admin.site.unregister(User)    
  admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: Nothing comes up on the template. I wanna see the field profile views but it doesn't show up. If I use the admin, I can see it. How do I show it on the template? Are all my codes correct? Thanks for the help. (Using Django 1.8 if that matters)

Comment: Nothing comes up on the template. I wanna see the field profile views but it doesn't show up. If I use the admin, I can see it. How do I show it on the template? Are all my codes correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You didn't mention that admin user works. That's a pretty important clue

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know it is, still new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack done

Comment: The code looks correct. Is `{{ user.username }}` shows something in template?

Comment: @AlbertTugushev yep, it gives me the username, same as {{ user }}

Comment: Hey guys, it worked! After checking and checking, I noticed I had this code which was not needed:


 def __unicode__(self): #Python3 is __str__
  return self.username.account_type

I removed and it works perfectly using:
{{ user.userprofile.profile_views }}



Thanks all for trying!